# I got "Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out" when i put ListView inside column

Tags: android, dart, flutter

i recently making a ListView inside the Column and SingleChildScrollView
but it show me an error like "NEEDS PAINT" or something.. here's my body code

```
body: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Text("Hoi");
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

i want to return "Hoi" 4 times.. but it showed me something like this

```
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6c04f relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `shrinkWrap` property of the `ListView`.

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        ...
```

More info: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html

And don't forget to return a `Widget` inside `itemBuilder`

```
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Text("Hoi"); 
          },
```

Comment: its not showing an error right now but the "Hoi" does not showed up